# how do you pass a value to a @property in python?

Tags: python, oop, decorator

So I'm writing a python script that modifies TV show titles. this is more for practice than anything. I'm trying to use the @property decorator, but I was under the misconception that when you do "var.property" I thought that the var would get passed to the property... so I'm trying to get splitName() to be able to use the hasDots property from the base class, but I'm not sure how you would pass the name Var into the property. I know I could do this with a method, but I'm trying to learn how to use properties. the splitName() method is going to be the main method once I can get the base class to work properly.

any help on this would be greatly appreciated. also I'm pretty new to python, so if I'm doing anything that is "unpythonic" let me know.

```
exceptibleExts = ['.avi','.mkv','mp4']

class Base(object):

    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        self.isTvShow()


    # this method will return the file name
    def fileName(self):
        for name in self.source:
            name, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
            yield name, ext


    @property
    def isTvShow(self):
        names = self.fileName()
        for name in names:
            if str(name[1]) in exceptibleExts and str(name[1]).startswith('.') == False:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    @property
    def hasDots(self):
        names = self.fileName()
        for name in names:
            if '.' in str(name[0]):
                return True
            else: 
                return False


    @property
    def hasDashes(self):
        names = self.fileName()
        for name in names:
            if '-' in str(name[0]):
                return True
            else:
                return False

    @property
    def startswithNumber(self):
        names = self.fileName()
        for name in names:
            if str(name[0].lstrip()[0].isdigit()):
                return True
            else:
                return False

    @property
    def hasUnderscore(self):
        names = self.fileName()
        for name in names:
            if '_' in str(name[0]):
                return True
            else:
                return False

class names(Base):
    def __init__(self, source):
        self.source = source
        #pass

        self.splitName()

    #this method returns true if the show title is in the file name... if not it will return false
    def hasShowTitle(self):
        pass



    def splitName(self):
        #names = self.fileNames
        showInfo = {}
        for name in self.fileName():
            print name.hasDots
```

Comment: What is "what you're trying to do"?  What does the code not do that you want it to do?

Comment: I'm trying to get splitName() to be able to use the hasDots property from the base class, but I'm not sure how you would pass the name Var into the property. I know I could do this with a method, but I'm trying to learn how to use properties.

Comment: Try at the beginning write your code in procedural style. Right now your code is ugly and there are hard to understand what you want to do. For example "for name in self.fileName()" name is string it doen't has method hasDots and using camelCase is not phythonic. Lets try start from basics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good idea to read documentation carefully when you are learning something.

Look at the third code example here http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

this is how you define setters and deleters for the properties defined using built-in `property` decorator.

P.S.: Corresponding Python 2 documentation is here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property

Comment: thank you for your response. this was very helpful... I've changed my coding structure based off of your suggestions.